# Wicked_pdf - Googlevisualr donut chart not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, google-visualization, wicked-pdf

I am working in rails 3 application and displaying donut chart with pieHole option. It's displaying on my web page but it's doesn't work on PDF. I wants to print donut chart on PDF file. Anybody know what is the issue? Please help.

For PDF, I am using wicked_pdf gem.

Gemfile

```
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem "google_visualr", ">= 2.1"
```

model.rb

```
  opts = { :title => chart_name, fontName: 'Open Sans', :legend => 'bottom', colors: IM_CHART_COLORS, pieHole: 0.4 }
  if !interactive.present?
    chart = GoogleVisualr::Interactive::PieChart.new(data_table, opts)
  else
    chart = GoogleVisualr::Image::PieChart.new(data_table, opts)
  end
```